# retrieve posts / query firebase swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am attempting to retrieve a list of Posts ("Planits - in my apps language") from firebase. My goal is to display a specific users posts within a table view on their profile. I have written a function to retrieves posts and query them by a sender ID so that the user see's their posts on their profile. But at the end of the query when i try to print out the appended array, i keep getting an empty array, so i can not go further on to populate the table view. Please any suggestions on where i went wrong, attached is a screen shot of my firebase nodes and the function i wrote. thanks

[image]

```
func retrievePost(){

   ref = Database.database().reference()

    let myPlanitsRef = self.ref.child("planits")

    let query = myPlanitsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "senderId").queryEqual(toValue: "uid")
    print(query)

    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {

            for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                print(DataSnapshot.self)
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
                let myPostURL = dict["images"] as! String
                self.images.append(myPostURL)

            }

            //print(myPostURL) - DOES NOT PRING ANYTHING
            //print(self.images) - DOES NOT PRING ANYTHING
        }


    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }

}
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        retrievePost()
        print(images) // PRINTS []
```

Comment: `queryEqual(toValue: "uid")` that seems like a mistake. You probably want to use the current user's UID, which you can get with `Auth.auth().currentUser.uid`. So `queryEqual(toValue: Auth.auth().currentUser.uid)`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen will try this as soon as I get back to my laptop. Thank you sir

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so after making the proposed changes. I still cannot pull any data out (headscrather). im beginning to think my issue maybe has something to do with the way my database nodes are structured maybe?